# How to wrap dynamic HTML from database around existing HTML via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to inject static XHTML code (that's being pulled from a database) and wrap it around existing HTML tags.

**HTML PAGE:**

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- Top half of XHTML wrapper goes here //-->

        <p>Inner Content Here</p>
        <!-- etc. --->
        <p>More Inner Content</p>

        <!-- Bottom half of XHTML wrapper goes here //-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**XHTML WRAPPER FROM DATABASE:**
*(this is variable content that comes from another system and is user created)*

This data comes down via json string.  I needs to be split() on the "{{INNER_CONTENT_PLACEHOLDER}}" placeholder and then wrapped *around* the content noted above.  There can be a LOT more wrapper code than I've shown here in my

```
<div class="myCustomBackground">
    <h1 class="myCustomHeader">MyCompany, Inc.</h2>
    <div class="container-padding">
        {{INNER_CONTENT_PLACEHOLDER}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to inject HTML without the javascript closing the tags so that they bottom half injection can be the closing tags?

Comment: Rich, can you flesh this out a little more, I am sure from there we can help. The DB is storing HTML fragments and you want to inject them in a template? Do you want to do on the client or the server?

Comment: @Bibberty Ulimately, I need this to work in a SPA app (we use Vue.js).  My customers create their own custom branded UI wrapper template (the style and HTML around the content on each page) using a RichTextEditor and they just put in a placeholder as to where they want the functionality.  Then I store that in the DB.  This was easy to do with ASPX pages but with javascript/vue.js, you can't inject open-tags above and below your component controls because the javascript auto-closes all the top wrapper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an id attribute to the outer wrapper:

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body>
  <div id="outerdiv">
    <!-- Top half of XHTML wrapper goes here //-->

    <p>Inner Content Here</p>
    <!-- etc. --->
    <p>More Inner Content</p>

    <!-- Bottom half of XHTML wrapper goes here //-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and also the inner padding:

```
<div class="myCustomBackground">
   <h1 class="myCustomHeader">MyCompany, Inc.</h2>
   <div class="container-padding" id="innerdiv">
     {{INNER_CONTENT_PLACEHOLDER}}
   </div>
</div>
```

then you should be able select the content into a variable and then replace the content with the wrapper from the database, and finally insert the content from the variable into the inner wrapper:

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outerdiv');
var content = outer.innerHTML;
outer.innerHTML = dbstuff;

var inner = document.getElementById('innerdiv');
inner.innerHTML = content;
```

Comment: I might not have the ability to add that `id="innerdiv"` attribute in my scenario but I'll see if this can possibly work.  Ultimately, I need to get this to work in Vue.js so I was looking for a clean "inject top HTML above and inject bottom HTML below".

Comment: This does work but, unfortunately, I can't use in in my scenario because it causes my vue controls in the inner container to lose reactivity (yes, I realize I left that part out to simplify the question).  I need to be able to just wrap HTML around without affecting what's in the inner container.